# slide background cover and change the covered background image

Tags: jquery

i have a div with an image background, another div above starting with transparent. I want to slide in a faded png background in the duiv above, change the background and slide out to show it.

i have coded this, the problem is the sequence. the structure slide_in, change background, slide_out is mixed randomly.

```
var step = 20;                 // How many pixels to move per step
var current = -1920;            // The current pixel row
var imageWidth = 1920;        // Background image width
var headerWidth = 960;        // How wide the header is.
var init;

function slide_in(){
    current += step;
$('#bgfade').css("background-position",current+"px 0");
if(current==0) clearInterval(init);
}

var outstep = 20;                 // How many pixels to move per step
var outcurrent = 0;            // The current pixel row
var outimageWidth = 1920;        // Background image width
var outheaderWidth = 960;        // How wide the header is.
var outinit;

function slide_out(){
outcurrent -= step;
$('#bgfade').css("background-position",outcurrent+"px 0");
if(outcurrent==0) clearInterval(outinit);
}

$('#bgfade').click(function(){        
init = setInterval(slide_in, 1);
$('#bg').css('background-image','url(images/photo2.jpg)');
outinit = setInterval(slide_out, 1);
});
```

As the click event occurr, the first thing happens is the image is changed after it the background starts to slide out but it had never slide in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution using this plugin: http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/backgroundPosition/